# How to "ToString" Character Arrays of Large Quantities?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public static void PrependEntitiesToFile(string pathToFile)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[10000];
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathToFile);

    string renamedFile = file.FullName + ".orig";
    System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, renamedFile);

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(renamedFile))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file.FullName, false))
    {
        string entityDeclaration = "foo";
        sw.Write(entityDeclaration);
        string strFileContents = string.Empty;
        int read;
        while ((read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                strFileContents += buffer[i].ToString();
            }
        }
        sw.Write(strFileContents, 0, strFileContents.Length);

    }

    System.IO.File.Delete(renamedFile);
}
```

This code works but its SOOOOO SLOW because I am looping through each character in the `buffer` array and `ToString()`-ing it. Imagine how slow it is when its ingesting and duplicating a 823,000 character file.

Is there a way to convert a fully populated `buffer` to a string and add it at once rather than looping through each character in the array? Or, generically speaking, is there just a faster way to this?

I am so ashamed of this code.

Comment: why aren't you just using the overload that writes a buffer at a time? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf931t09.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, that's not why it's so slow. It's slow because you're doing a repeated [string concatenation and that's `O(n^2)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm). You'd see better performance if you used a `StringBuilder`. You could also just make an array of the characters, and call the [constructor of `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) that takes such an array.

But even better, skip the string all together, and just write the buffer out to `sw`.

Comment: Down stream there is a reason for storing it in a string. The reason is, based on a condition, the string may need to be prepended to the new file as its written in. I may just call the constructor of the string. This is definitely one of those times I may end up also using StringBuilder.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Regardless, your main issue is the repeated concatenations.

Comment: For an 800,000 char file, that means I will have a 8 "buffers" if each buffer stores up to 10,000 chars. Is there a way to cat character arrays together since I cant do buffer += buffer;? Othewise I am not sure how I will use the constructure of a string and pass in buffer just once.

Comment: by the way, thanks for calling me a Schlemiel... lol. Its true though, I am one. I started with C# and high level design, but not the small, low-level operations.

Comment: Yup. Declare a variable before the `while` loop: `var contents = Enumerable.Empty<char>();` Then, inside the loop, append the contents of the buffer to `contents` via `contents = contents.Concat(buffer)`. Then, when you are ready to construct the string, use `new String(contents.ToArray());`.

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass your character array to the `string` constructor:

```
string strFileContents = new string(buffer);
```

I expect that to be much faster.

Comment: It's not simple. He's repeatedly reading to the buffer. It's a doubly-nested loop.

Comment: Yeah, and I am not proud of it either.

Comment: @Jason:  It's a pretty huge improvement anyway.

Answer (score 1):

don't be, you are so close... i think, you can write the output like this:
you seem to be it looping it twice...

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(renamedFile))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file.FullName, false))
{
    string entityDeclaration = "foo";
    sw.Write(entityDeclaration);
    string strFileContents = string.Empty;
    int read;
    while ((read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        sw.Write(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I can use sw.write several times to get what I want. +1 for the help

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask *why* you are doing this. BEcause it looks like your goal is to move the contents of one file to another char-by-char with no other processing. In which case there are much better ways.

But even if you do need to read everything in, have a look at [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

Comment: I have an xml file that needs a series of entities in a doctype prepended to it because a client isn't sending the xml with entities already in them. The parser freaks out when it encounters nbsp. So I am makign a copy and holding the entity in a string. Ill look at ReadAllLines, its probably a better solution than char arrays.

Comment: it looks, like he is prepending "foo" to it. would a `seek(0)` or similar make sense?

Comment: @mindandmedia I added in foo for brevity sakes. Can you explain what seek is?

Comment: never mind that comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343044/c-prepending-to-beginning-of-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Just use the overload that takes a buffer, offset, and length and skip the conversion altogether.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(renamedFile))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file.FullName, false))
{
    string entityDeclaration = "foo";
    sw.Write(entityDeclaration);
    string strFileContents = string.Empty;
    int read;
    while ((read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        sw.Write( buffer, 0, read );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use String.  Use Stringbuilder instead.

In .NET, string are immutable, which means each time you change one, it makes a copy.  That slows it down over time.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do a GetString().  It reads in 2048 bytes at a time to do the conversion.  You can also specify an encoding type to handle different charsets.

```
public enum EncodingType 
{ 
    ASCII, 
    Unicode, 
    UTF7, 
    UTF8 
} 
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes) 
{ 
    return ByteArrayToString(bytes, EncodingType.Unicode); 
} 

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes, EncodingType encodingType) 
{ 
    System.Text.Encoding encoding=null; 
    switch (encodingType) 
    { 
    case EncodingType.ASCII: 
        encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
        break;    
    case EncodingType.Unicode: 
        encoding=new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding(); 
        break;    
    case EncodingType.UTF7: 
        encoding=new System.Text.UTF7Encoding(); 
        break;    
    case EncodingType.UTF8: 
        encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
        break;    
    } 
    return encoding.GetString(bytes); 
}
```