# Create File If File Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I need to get my code to read if file doesnt exist create else append. Right now it is reading if it does exist create and append. Here is the code:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
```

Would I do this?

```
if (! File.Exists(path))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
```

Edit:

```
string path = txtFilePath.Text;

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).FirstName);
            sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).LastName);
            sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).JobTitle);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path);

    foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).FirstName);
        sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).LastName);
        sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).JobTitle);
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) - this is doing exactly what you need in one single line of code..

Comment: @ShadowWizard Since this is tagged homework OP may actually be directed to show the conditional logic.

Comment: @Yuck - homework to reinvent the wheel? Yuck! ;)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can simply call

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
```

It will create the file if it doesn't exist and open the file for appending.

Edit:

This is sufficient:

```
string path = txtFilePath.Text;               
using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
  foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)                 
  {                    
    Employee e = (Employee)line; // unbox once
    sw.WriteLine(e.FirstName);                     
    sw.WriteLine(e.LastName);                     
    sw.WriteLine(e.JobTitle); 
  }                
}
```

But if you insist on checking first, you can do something like this, but I don't see the point.

```
string path = txtFilePath.Text;               


using (StreamWriter sw = (File.Exists(path)) ? File.AppendText(path) : File.CreateText(path))                 
{                      
    foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)                     
    {                         
      sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).FirstName);                         
      sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).LastName);                         
      sw.WriteLine(((Employee)line).JobTitle);                     
    }                  
}
```

Also, one thing to point out with your code is that you're doing a lot of unnecessary unboxing.  If you have to use a plain (non-generic) collection like `ArrayList`, then unbox the object once and use the reference.

However, I perfer to use `List<>` for my collections:

```
public class EmployeeList : List<Employee>
```

Answer (score 21):

or:

```
using FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
using StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
// ...
```

Comment: For this case you would get an IOException because fileStream still locks the file when stream writer would like write to it. Instead pass the fileStream as argument to StreamWriter constructor.

Answer (score 18):

You don't even need to do the check manually, File.Open does it for you. Try:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append))) 
{
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

Answer (score 7):

**2021**

Just use [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-5.0), which creates the file if it does not exist:

```
File.AppendAllText("myFile.txt", "some text");
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to negate `File.Exists(path)` if you want to check if the file *doesn't* exist.

Comment: -1 Checking for file existence before opening the file is a wrong pattern. This introduces race conditions. See the other answers and [my comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907682/create-a-txt-file-if-doesnt-exist-and-if-it-does-append-a-new-line#comment101632299_9907682).

Answer (score 1):

This works as well for me

```
string path = TextFile + ".txt";

if (!File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
{
    File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close();
}
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
{
    w.WriteLine("{0}", "Hello World");
    w.Flush();
    w.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will enable appending to file using StreamWriter

```
 using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("YourFilePath", true)) {...}
```

This is default mode, not append to file and create a new file.

```
using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("YourFilePath", false)){...}
                           or
using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("YourFilePath")){...}
```

Anyhow if you want to check if the file exists and then do other things,you can use

```
using (StreamWriter sw = (File.Exists(path)) ? File.AppendText(path) : File.CreateText(path))
            {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example

```
    string rootPath = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
        rootPath += "MTN";
        if (!(File.Exists(rootPath)))
        {
            File.CreateText(rootPath);
        }
```

Comment: -1 Checking for file existence before opening the file is a wrong pattern. This introduces race conditions. See the other answers and [my comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907682/create-a-txt-file-if-doesnt-exist-and-if-it-does-append-a-new-line#comment101632299_9907682).

Comment: My pattern like contains in linq. I mean it is normal. Sometimes files necessary authorization, opening the file should be the second solution instead of our answer.

Comment: @MetinAtalayI am sorry, I do not fully understand your comment. My concern is that if the file is created -- externally -- after `if (!(File.Exists(...)))`, but before `File.CreateText(...)`, then it is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Url> AddURLToFile(Urls urls, Url url)
{
    string filePath = @"D:\test\file.json";
    urls.UrlList.Add(url);

    //if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    //    using (System.IO.File.Delete(filePath));

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(urls.UrlList));

    //using (StreamWriter sw = (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) ? System.IO.File.AppendText(filePath) : System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath))
    //{
    //    sw.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(urls.UrlList));
    //}
    return urls.UrlList;
}

private List<Url> ReadURLToFile()
{
    //  string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"App_Data\file.json");
    string filePath = @"D:\test\file.json";

    List<Url> result = new List<Url>(); ;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        using (System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath)) ;



    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Url>>(file.ReadToEnd());
        file.Close();
    }
    if (result == null)
        result = new List<Url>();

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information why this code might answer the question. Furthermore provide a [mcve].