# how to clear text file content c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

i want clear text file contet with this method

```
private void writeTextFile(string filePath, string text)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        File.Create(filePath).Close();

    }
    using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filePath,"");
        tw.WriteLine(text);
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

but i get this error

```
The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process.
```

but this not open in anywhere ,

please help me
thank's

Answer (score 16):

That's because you're creating a `StreamWriter`, then using `File.WriteAllText`.  Your File is already being accessed with the `StreamWriter`.

`File.WriteAllText` does just that, writes the entire string you pass to it to a file.  `StreamWriter` is unnecessary if you're going to use `File.WriterAllText`.

If you don't care about overwriting an existing file, you can do this:

```
private void writeTextFile(string filePath, string text)
{
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
}
```

If you want to use `StreamWriter` (which, by the way, `File.WriteAllText` uses, it just hides it), and append to the file, you can do this (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383053/create-file-if-file-does-not-exist)):

```
using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
    tw.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Or at that point just delete the method entirely and have the caller call `File.WriteAllText` directly, because this method accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @Servy yup!  I was just going with the existing template.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StreamWriter` for creating a file for write and use `Truncate` to write with clearing previous content.

```
StreamWriter writeFile;
writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Truncate, myIsolatedStorage));
writeFile.WriteLine("String");
writeFile.Close();
```

This use `FileMode.Truncate`

> `Truncate` Specifies that an existing file it to be opened and then truncated so that its size is zero bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your file already exists and you want to clear its contents before populating it or whatever, I found the best way to do this with StreamWriter is..

```
// this line does not create test.txt file, assuming that it already exists, it will remove the contents of test.txt 
Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(Path.GetFullPath(C:\test.txt), False)

// this line will now be inserted into your test.txt file
sw.Write("hey there!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// I decided to use this solution
// this section is to clear MyFile.txt
     using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"MyPath\MyFile.txt", false))
     {
       foreach(string line in listofnames)
       {
          sw.Write(""); // change WriteLine with Write
       }
        sw.Close();
      }
    // and this section is to copy file names to MyFile.txt
        using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"MyPath\MyFile.txt", true))
        {
        foreach(string line in listofnames)
        {
            file.WriteLine(line);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specify false in the second parameter of the constructor for **StreamWriter**( route, **false** )

```
String ruta = @"C:\Address\YourFile".txt";

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(ruta, false))
{
     for ( int i = 0; i < settings.Length; ++i )
         file.WriteLine( settings[ i ] );

     file.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you locking the file by initializing `StreamWriter` onto `filePath` and then trying to call `File.WriteAllText` which also internally attempts to lock the file and eventually end up with an exception being thrown.

Also from what it looks you are trying to clear the file's content and then write something in.
Consider the following:

```
private void writeTextFile(string filePath, string text) {
    using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))  //second parameter is `Append` and false means override content            
        tw.WriteLine(text);

}
```

Comment: I think the second parameter is not append, but rather the encoding.

Comment: There are two constructors, one with encoding as second param and another one with boolean as second param.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `FileStream` with `FileMode.Create`?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Look at the MSDN of [FileMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netcore-3.1#fields)

> Create
> Specifies that the operating system should **create a new file**. **If the file already exists, it will be overwritten**. This requires Write permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate. If the file already exists but is a hidden file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

**Overwritten** will cover/remove/clean/delete all existed file data.
if you would like to use `StreamWriter`, use `new StreamWriter(fs)`.