# XNA - How to add settings.ini to the game by default when installing?

Tags: c#, xna, ini, content-pipeline

I got a settings.ini file, which I want to be included in the game when installed.
It should be in a folder called Settings and it should be in the same directory as the rest of the game (Like the executable and the default content folder).

I thought I would just add an extra empty content project to my game solution and add the settings.ini file to it.

Guess What! It doesn't work.

It gives me the following error:

> Error 6 Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "Settings.ini".
>   There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the
>   importer that handles this file type in your project.
>   PATH_TO_GAME\Settings\Settings.ini

I googled a bit, but it looks like I need to write my own content pipeline.

Is there a better/more easy way to do this? I don't want to waste my time on writing this very difficult part.

PS. If I install the game and add the settings.ini to the settings directory, I am able to write into and read from the settings.ini file. But now I have to add the settings.ini file manually, which I don't want. I want it to be supplied with the game when you install it.

Comment: You can make your game create that file if it is not detected in its folder. This post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907682/create-a-txt-file-if-its-not-exist-and-if-it-exist-write-a-line-with-c-sharp

Comment: Hm, yes. That is also something I should think about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your game project solution (not content project!), add a `Settings` folder, and the `Settings.ini` file. You might use `Add -> Existing Item...` for the file if you already have it.

[image: Add a settings file]

Under `Properties` for the file, set `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

[image]

Your settings file will now be deployed with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Take all the contents of your .ini file and put them into your game's code:

```
string path = @"path\to\your.ini";
if (!File.Exists(path))
    using (var sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
    sw.WriteLine(@"This is the .ini file text.");
    sw.WriteLine(@"It can contain all sorts of characters, like !@#$%^&*()_+|");
    sw.WriteLine(@"But you need to use double quotes "" so you don't get errors");
    }
```