# Taking user input from a textbox to create a text file name

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, streamwriter

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C#

I currently have a form which, among other items, has a textbox for the user to enter an id number. I want to be able to 'take' this number and create a text file with the ID number as a file name.

I have been able to write to a file using the OpenFileDialog and Streamwriter, but this requires the user to click the "Save Location" button and browse to a file location, then enter the text for the file they want created.

I would rather have the program create the .txt file based on the id number so that they can just enter their ID and then press enter to start the program.

Is this possible?

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907682/create-a-txt-file-if-its-not-exist-and-if-it-exist-write-a-line-with-c-sharp

Comment: What @Goose said. And if you want them to select a folder (but still automatically create the file name), take a look at [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Goose I thought I had searched other answers well before posting my question. Parts of that answer definitely help my query.

Comment: Just wondering why someone downvoted my question. The downmark is if "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" The fact I wrote I am already using Streamwriter and OpenFileDialog shows that I have already attempted this on my own. If the question was unclear, there is a comment area right here to ask for clarification. The question is clearly useful, as by asking it, I have been able to solve the problem. If you are going to downvote someones question, the polite thing to do would be to state why you believe it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible and it's trivial to do. If you want to use your `StreamWriter` just replace my `File.WriteAllText` with your `StreamWriter` code.

```
button_click_handler(fake args)
{
     string fileName = MyTextBox.Text;
     File.WriteAllText(basePath + fileName, "file contents");
}
```

Comment: So this will create the file if it doesn't exist and add to it if it doesn't?

Comment: @smokeAndMirrors it overwrites the file if it's there. It just writes no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. The only point not clear in your question is where you want to create this text file and what you want to store inside it.

```
 string fileName = txtForFileName.Text;
 // create a path to the MyDocuments folder
 string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.MyDocuments);
 // Combine the file name with the path
 string fullPath = Path.Combine(docPath, fileName);

 // Note that if the file exists it is overwritten
 // If you want to APPEND then use: new StreamWriter(fullPath, true)
 using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
 {
    sw.WriteLine("Hello world");
 }
```

I think that you could find very useful looking at this MSDN page about [Common I/O Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do that.

```
 string thepath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}","C:\\PutDestinationHere\\",idTextBox.text,".txt");

 using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(thepath))
  {
     writer.WriteLine();
  }
```